# _GTGlyphStorage prepareWithCapacity:preallocated, crash, unrecongnized selector send to

Tags: ios, crash

[crash image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkLQ5.png)

[new crash image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxOnQ.png)

I can not located the problem code.

did anyone knows what happened.
it is happened occasionally, not every time.

from the new crash image, i think UITextField is release more.

I confuse that in arc mode, member variables is strong default, property is defined by the @property
when i define a member variable UITextField * _inputField , and then define a property @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UITextField * inputField
is the _input is strong?

1. this is .h code

   ```
   @interface BFMobLoginInput : UIControl <UITextFieldDelegate>
   {
       UITextField * _inputField;
       eBFMobLoginInputType _type;
       NSString * _msgId;
   }

   @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UITextField * inputField;               

   @end
   ```

2.the code in .m, init code，i use as follow:

```
_inputField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
```

Comment: You should really read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @iPeter, sorry, i am new to stackoverflow. The crash is hard to descript, so i    upload a pic.

Comment: Briefly describe about What you have done, where the crash is happening and show some code so that we can understand where is your problem. @flyingeagle

Comment: @iPeter, ok, but code is many, and i cannot located problem code

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint, the breakpoint will stop execution at the line where the crash is taking place. @flyingeagle

Comment: @iPeter, thank you, i put the source code to the demo not the framework, and catch a new crash image, i uploaded it. From the crash image, i see that some object become zombie object, but i used arc mode to code, why has a zombie object?